# R: Haar Wavelet transform

Tags: r

I want to run a Haar wavelet-transform on a time serie:

```
k<-c(4,6,10,12,8,6,5,5)
```

I do this job with this code (I am using `Wavethresh` package)

```
ywd<-wd(k,filter.number=2,family="DaubExPhase")
c<-accessC(ywd,level=2)
c
```

the output is:

`7.639474 15.884519  9.356473  6.717514`

There is not why I am expecting for trends or [averages part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet#Haar_matrix)

what I expected is

[image]

what is the problem of my code, and how can I do Haar wavelet transform in R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In package `wavelets` you can do a Haar wavelet transform using function `dwt` (discrete wave tranform) and argument `filter` set to `"haar"`:

```
library(wavelets)
k <- c(4,6,10,12,8,6,5,5)
w <- dwt(k, filter="haar")
```

`dwt` objects are quite complex S4 objects so i wouldn't be able to explain what each part of it means (knowing nothing about wavelets myself), i would instead suggest you to read `?dwt`, but what you're looking for seems to be contained in slot `V`:

```
w@V[[1]]
          [,1]
[1,]  7.071068
[2,] 15.556349
[3,]  9.899495
[4,]  7.071068
```

Here is, for information, everything the object contains:

```
An object of class "dwt"
Slot "W":
$W1
          [,1]
[1,]  1.414214
[2,]  1.414214
[3,] -1.414214
[4,]  0.000000

$W2
     [,1]
[1,]    6
[2,]   -2

$W3
          [,1]
[1,] -2.828427


Slot "V":
$V1
          [,1]
[1,]  7.071068
[2,] 15.556349
[3,]  9.899495
[4,]  7.071068

$V2
     [,1]
[1,]   16
[2,]   12

$V3
         [,1]
[1,] 19.79899


Slot "filter":
Filter Class: Daubechies
Name: HAAR
Length: 2
Level: 1
Wavelet Coefficients: 7.0711e-01 -7.0711e-01
Scaling Coefficients: 7.0711e-01 7.0711e-01


Slot "level":
[1] 3

Slot "n.boundary":
[1] 0 0 0

Slot "boundary":
[1] "periodic"

Slot "series":
     [,1]
[1,]    4
[2,]    6
[3,]   10
[4,]   12
[5,]    8
[6,]    6
[7,]    5
[8,]    5

Slot "class.X":
[1] "numeric"

Slot "attr.X":
list()

Slot "aligned":
[1] FALSE

Slot "coe":
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `filter.number=1`.

Sources:
https://books.google.com/books?id=5gLAQLTl4iQC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=wavethresh+wd+haar+dwt&source=bl&ots=qkX2U1QinD&sig=vj28jT6xP6tlRiL7_REtpHEf-qI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMk7yBmezYAhXrTN8KHWIoD_0Q6AEITTAJ#v=onepage&q=wavethresh%20wd%20haar%20dwt&f=false

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daubechies_wavelet